# Java problem consuming WebService hosted on IIS secured by WindowsAuthentication

Tags: java, web-services, iis, ntlm-authentication

**APP Description**

The APP that behaving improperly is an Android APP that allows the user to take a photo from his phone and then upload it to a Sharepoint CMS.

**Detailed problem description**

On a Java App, I'm sending a POST HTTP request containing the bytes of an image as base64 to a SOAP WebService hosted on IIS. This WebService is secured using Windows Authentication. I've configured the Java program to send credentials whenever a request is made. When I check the HTTP response code it is **HTTP 401 Unauthorized**. I'm unable to check the response contents.

**Observations of note**

The Java debugger doesn't step into the *getPasswordAuthentication* method of the *Authenticator* class as it should be.

**APP Specs**

- Programming language: Java
- Type of application: Android APP
- Code location: Inside an AsyncTask
- Endpoint type: SOAP WebService
- Endpoint authentication: Windows Authentication

**Relevant code**

*Connection setup*

```java
URL url = new URL(ENDPOINT_URL);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// Enable POST
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

*Authenticator setup to always send stored credentials*

```java
Authenticator.setDefault(new NTLMAuthenticator());
```

*NTLMAuthenticator class*

```java
public class NTLMAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD".toCharArray());
    }
}
```

*Request POST content setup*

```java
try (OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream()) {
    String baseRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><Upload xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/ois/\"><strListName>%s</strListName><strFolder /><bytes>%s</bytes><fileName>%s</fileName><fOverWriteIfExist>true</fOverWriteIfExist></Upload></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
    File f = new File(PATH_TO_FILE);
    byte[] fileBytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(f);
    String fileBase64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(fileBytes, 0);
    outputStream.write(String.format(baseRequest, LIST_NAME, fileBase64, FILE_NAME).getBytes());
    outputStream.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Response READ*

```java
int response_code = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    // **response_code IS HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED**
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()))) {
        // **Unreachable code**
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Read response line by line
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you diable windows authentication and do not use Authenticator.setDefault(new NTLMAuthenticator()), can it upload photo successfully? If you want to auto login by using windows authentication, the client and server should in the same domain.